# Making a generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method for filtering/searching which now is written for every `Windows Form` that offers searching. I'm trying to make a generic method in the base class so I can avoid this large amount of repeating code.

Here is the original code which I want to modify:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    GridFilter filter = new GridFilter();
    filter.AddRule(dgvColDescription.DataPropertyName, txtDescription.Text);

    if (cboColor.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        filter.AddRule(dgvColMaterialColorId.DataPropertyName, cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString());
    }
    ...
    //a lot more of this filter.AddRule stuff 
    ...
 }
```

There are two things here I think - the need of instance for `GridFilter` and the two types of control that I need to use.

Having said that here is my try for a generic method:

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules<T>(Control ctrl, String str) where T : GridFilter
{
    T filter;
    if (ctrl is ComboBox)
    {
        if ((ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            filter.AddRule(/*dgvColMaterialColorId.DataPropertyName*/ str, (ctrl as ComboBox).SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
    }

    if (ctrl is TextBox)
    {
        filter.AddRule(/*dgvColCode.DataPropertyName*/str, ctrl.Text);
    }
}
```

There are some comments because I'm still not sure if I can pass the commented part as string, but the bigger problem for me is the error that I get from the `IDE` about the `filter` variable which is:

> Use of unassigned local variable "filter"

Is it possible to make a generic method out of it after all and how can I do that?

Comment: The IDE error refers to the fact that it does not see a line where you create an instance of that object.

Comment: From the code, it looks like you want to make an extension method, so you can call myGridFilterVar.AddFilterRules. To do that, remove T filter from the body and define the method as AddFilterRules<T>(this T filter, Control ctrl, String str) where ... Extension method must be static as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the [`new()` contraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) to your method.

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules<T>(Control ctrl, String str) where T : GridFilter, new()
```

and then

```
T filter = new T();
```

Either that or pass T in as a parameter:

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules<T>(T filter, Control ctrl, String str) where T : GridFilter
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work when I need to pass 10-15 controls. Creating a new Filter for each seems to me like a problem but I may be wrong?

Comment: @Leron The `new()` constraint simple states that the generic type must have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Generic Type parameters are exactly that, a _type_.  If you want to use a specific _instance_ of GridFilter, you need to pass it in as a regular argument.

Comment: @RoadieRich It just depends on if Leron coded his filters to build themselves or if he needs to build them and pass them in.

Comment: @Leron In that case, you probably don't need the generic argument at all, just specify the argument as a `GridFilter`.

Comment: You are right, I don't know why I try to make everything generic :)

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct, but you have two other problems:

1. You are not initializing `T` to anything.  It is a `null` reference at the point you are trying to use it.  Did you intend to pass in a `T`?
2. You're not *doing anything* with the `T`.  Should you be *returning* the `T`?  Or assigning it to a property of some other object?

If you pass in a reference to a `T` and then modify it within the method, then both problems are solved:

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules<T>(T filter, Control ctrl, String str)
     where T : GridFilter
{
    ...
}
```

However in that case your method doesn't need to be generic at all:

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules(GridFilter filter, Control ctrl, String str)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to use a single instance of `DataFilter` so I can add all filter rulse to the same object. That's why I want to instantiate `GridFilter` in my `LoadData()` metod and then pass the object instance when I'm calling `AddFilterRules<T>` is this a wrong way to think about generic methods?

Answer (score 1):

**Why do you want to use a generic method?**

If your filter is always a `GridFilter` you can just use that type in your method. Even if you use a derived class like `SpecialGridFilter` this would still work. The fact that in your original method you create a new `GridFilter` each time means that you can do so in your new method. Hence there is no need for a new method despite the fact that you pass some values to it now.

It looks like you mix up type parameters with ordinary parameters. Having a type parameter doesn't mean you get an instance of that type. It just means you can use the same algorithms for different types without explicitly coding them for each type.

If you really need a generic implementation you can use a type constraint on the generic parameter `where T : GridFilter, new()`. This allows you to create a `new T()` in your generic method.

**Where will the new method be implemented?**

I don't know how `GridFilter` is implemented now but it looks like `AddRule` modifies it. If so you shouldn't create a new instance each time because all changes will get lost. `AddFilterRules` should therefore also be a member of the `GridFilter` class and each form should have an instance of a `GridFilter`.

If you cannot change the implementation of `GridFilter` you can still use an extension method. If it is correct to create a new `GridFilter` each time you can have an extension method on the `Form` type. This depends on how `GridFilter` works.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an instance of T:

```
T filter = new GridFilter();
```

If T is always going to be a `GridFilter`, you may as well replace T by GridFilter:

```
protected virtual void AddFilterRules<GridFilter>(Control ctrl, String str)
{
    GridFilter filter = new GridFilter();
    ...
}
```

However, I don't think you should use a generic method at all. You should create a method that returns a GridFilter:

```
protected virtual GridFilter AddFilterRules(Control ctrl, String str)
{
    GridFilter filter = new GridFilter();
    ...

    return filter;
}
```